# What is :_* and How it implement in Scala?

Tags: scala, symbols

What i know:

```
scala> def fx(s: String *) = s.foreach(println)
fx: (s: String*)Unit

scala> val lst = List("1","2","3")
lst: List[java.lang.String] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> fx(lst:_*)
1
2
3
```

What i want to know:

> 1. How can I implement `:_*`? by map?
> 2. Is there any other way that replace it?
> 3. How :_* defined in Scala?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is only a syntactic sugar to indicates to the compiler that you already provide a sequence of elements, there is no other "implementation" of it. For more information, you can refer to the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (§6.6, p. 78)

Answer (score 1):

For a method that takes variable arguments `:_*` means you want to pass the members of a collection as the variable arguments.

The corresponding varargs example to yours above:

```
scala> fx("a", "b", "c")
a
b
c
```

You can't implement -- it is a language feature.   It doesn't mean anything outside the context of calling a varargs method.